# Have Implementation in Classpath code to be used in Library

Tags: java, scala, reflection, scala-reflect

I am trying to write a Utility library (jar),

**Inside Library**

```
interface ConfigBuilder
{
  public Configuration buildConfiguration()
}

class SomeLogic
{
  private void someMethod()
  {
    ConfigBuilder  builder = // GET IMPLEMETATION OBJECT FROM IMPLEMENTOR OF LIBRARY ??
    Configuration c = builder.buildConfiguration();
    method2(c)
    //Some logic
  }
}
```

How can I do this ??
I am using Gradle as build tool. As being library We don't have an implementation class.
Max we can do is - Who ever is implementing this library create a class with name `com.xyz.lib.implimentation.ConfigBuilderImpl`

implementing `ConfigBuilder` Interface

**What I tried**
I was

```
this.getClass.getClassLoader.loadClass("com.xyz.lib.implimentation.ConfigBuilderImpl")
```

Then I am getting Exception

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.xyz.lib.implimentation.ConfigBuilderImpl
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:382)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424)
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357)
```

Comment: That looks like **Java** code, why did you tag it with **Scala**? - Anyways, the best idea is to leet your caller to pass you the implementation explicitly instead of relying in black magic.

Comment: I have been a java developer for some time, learning scala, Both are JVM based the concept seems the same in both.

Comment: So why not tagging **Kotlin**, **Groovy**, **Jython**, **Cloujure**, etc? You didn't mentioned anything related to **Scala** in the question. Also, which concept? Runtime reflection based dependency injection? Sorry, but no; that may be very common in **Java** but it is usually avoided in **Scala**.

Answer (score 0):

You can use SPI, the Service Provider Interface.

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/ext/basics/spi.html